# Scan automatically to Alfresco community edition

Tags: metadata, alfresco

I  want a simple solution to scan automatically with metadata to alfresco please , i tried Ephesoft but i couldn't do the integration correctly .

I found chronoscan , libertex and ifresco but no chance .  any solution with a documentation could really help me . thank you on advance .

btw i'm using alfresco community edition .

Comment: Give more information what errors you have faced with these tools and what steps you have taken to resolve them ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer these links for Ephesoft Alfresco
Addons
https://addons.alfresco.com/featured/document-capture-ephesoft

https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/ephesoft

Integration links

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-integrate-alfresco-with-ephesoft

http://www.algoworks.com/blog/alfresco-and-ephesoft-integration/

with CMIS refer this link

http://www.ephesoft.com/video-ephesoft-integrates-with-alfresco-using-cmis

https://tpeelen.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/configuring-ephesoft-and-alfresco-for-cmis-integration/